# How does $\frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d} x}\Big{|}_{x+dx} = \frac{{\rm d} u}{{\rm d} x}\Big{|}_{x} + \frac{{\rm d}^2 u}{{\rm d}x^2}{{\rm d} x}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am currently studying some equations related to a flexible beam bending problem, but I don't fully comprehend how this relation is being derived below:

$$\frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d} x}\Big{|}_{x+dx} = \frac{{\rm d} u}{{\rm d} x}\Big{|}_{x} + \frac{{\rm d}^2 u}{{\rm d}x^2}{{\rm d} x}$$

I don't think its derived as a result of something specific to the beam bending problem, but I've attached an image below (from some lecture notes) of what the diagram shows, just in case. Below, $Q(x)$ is just the tension of the beam during an applied distributed load.

---

[image: Flexible Beam].

---

Can anyone explain to me how the differential on the left hand side is transformed into the right hand side? Maybe I'm missing something fundamental, I haven't looked at calculus in a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v := u'$.  Since $({\rm d} x)^2 = 0$, the Taylor expansion of $v$ at $x$ is just $$v (x + {\rm d} x) = v(x) + v'(x) \, {\rm d} x$$